# Ionic deeplinks abre el navegador en vez de la app

Tags: ionic, ios

Estoy integrando deeplinks con una aplicación en ionic usando el plugin de [cordova](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-plugin-deeplinks), en android todo funciona bien, pero en IOS abre el link directamente en el browser en vez de abrir la app.

Ya revise el archivo AASA en [branch.io](https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/?_gl=1*343k8l*_ga*MTQ4NTA0NDU4OS4xNzAxMjg1ODMw*_ga_KSDD8Y11CT*MTcwMzExNDgzMC4zLjEuMTcwMzEyMDk5Mi41OS4wLjA.#resultsbox)

Tambien ya agregue el associated domain en xcode

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya probe tanto en el emulador de xcode como en un dispositivo real, ya no se me ocurre que otros problemas podrian haber